# Problems deploying Symfony2 project

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, web-deployment

I'm having difficulties deploying my symfony2 project to `http://beachteamvandenbroecke-engels.be/`.

I don't have access to ssh on my server so I had to copy the project folder to my website manually. 
I've exported my local db and inserted it on the server. 
I've changed the settings in my `config/parameters.yml` .

But now when I want to go to http://beachteamvandenbroecke-engels.be/web/app_dev.php (haven't set my .htaccess file for redirecting) I get this error:

```
You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.
```

In my app_dev.php :

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow! Show some efforts! It's written why **RIGHT IN YOUR CODE**!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as the comment sais

`// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.`

remove this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

this is just checking that your IP address is allowed. And allowed IP's are contained in this array `array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')`.

**NOTE**

in prod env you'll need to point to `app.php` not `app_dev.php`

**EDIT**

in order to switch to `PROD` env, run this command:

```
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

`--env=prod` will provide to point to `app.php` instead of `app_dev.php`

`--no-debug` will exit the debug mode like it won't show the Symfony debug bar in the browser..

Comment: It's better to use web/app.php (as you just said in your note)

Comment: @Debflav yes exactly, but as i mentioned in the EDIT, this will be done from the console with the appropriate command :-)